# mp3 recorder on a website, mp3 licencing issue

Tags: licensing, mp3

I dont know if this is right question to ask here. But let me ask, I am working on site where I will put a flash audio recorder, That will record voice in mp3 file and save on the server for later play. Do i need some kind of license to create mp3 files.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards

Parminder

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a license to create MP3 files, since you're using original content, not someone else's.

You may need a license to use an MP3 encoding library, depending on which you are using. Some MP3 codecs are free so if you use one of those, you will most likely need no license at all.

Comment: thanks ssamuel, I am buying this product which create mp3 using Lame encoding.